# Как обратиться к другому слоту Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь в конструкторе B вызвать слот `A::toExit()`. Как исправить ошибку?

```
class A:: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    explicit A(QWidget *parent = 0);

    A *a;
    public slots:
    void toExit();
}

class B:: public QWinget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    explicit B(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    QPushButton *but;   
    B *b;
    A *a;

    but = new QPushButton(tr("Кнопка"));
    connect(but, SIGNAL(clicked()), a, SLOT(toExit())); //здесь ошибка
}
```

Comment: Вы не пытаетесь вызвать слот. А какая ошибка мы должны догадаться сами конечно же? Держите бесплатный совет: либо Вы будете писать нормальные вопросы, где будет приведено всё, что нужно, чтобы понять проблему, либо Вы просто не будете получать ответов. P.S. Код приведённый в вопросе это просто мусор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю вопрос не в том как вызвать слот `A::toExit`, а как по нажатию кнопки, находящейся в виджете `В` вызывать необходимый слот находящийся в главном окне.
Примерно так:

```
class A: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit A(QWidget *parent = 0)
    {
        // ...
        connect(widgetWithButton->but, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &A::toExit )
        //...
    }

    public slots:
        void toExit();

    B* widgetWithButton;
}

class B: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    explicit B(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    QPushButton* but;   
}
```

Первым аргументом в `connect` передается указатель объекта который будет генерировать сигнал, второй аргумент, адрес сигнала, третий аргумент это адрес объекта который будет принимать сигнал, четвертый - адрес слота.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде вы пытаетесь сделать соединение к объекту которого нет.

```
A *a; // Здесь есть указатель, но он не указывает на какой-либо объект.
A *a = new A(); // а этот указатель уже можно использовать
```